# Populate a drop down based of different drop down's selection

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot

My spring boot java thymeleaf project has a form with a drop down populated from a SQL table. The form has a second drop down that I want to populate based off which item is selected in the first drop down.To do this I will need to pass the ID of the value of the first drop down. I know I have to use JQuery to accomplish this, but do I need to do two ajax calls? One to pass the selected id, and one to retrieve the new list for the second drop down? Should the get ajax be after the post ajax or inside it? 
Could someone help me better understand the best way to achieve what I am trying to do?

This is what I have so far:

```html
<td> <select  class="form-control" id="parentCo" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].parentCompany}" required="true" >
      <option th:value="select">-Select-</option>
      <th:block th:each="carrier : ${carriers}">
               <option th:value="${carrier.parentCompanyCarrier}" th:text="${carrier.parentCompanyCarrier}" th:data="${carrier.id}"></option>
       </th:block>
        </select>
</td>
<td><select class="form-control" id="writeCos" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].writingCompany}" required="true" >

     </select>
</td>
```

```js
//grab value of selected carrier
$('#parentCo').on('change', function(event){
    $('#parentCo').find('option:selected');
    var id = $(this).attr('data');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/carrierAjax",
        data: id,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data, jqXHR){
            console.log('sent ID successfully')
        }
    });
    
     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/carrierAjax",
        data: carrierUmbrellas,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data, jqXHR){
            //do afor each here to append each writeCo
            data.each(function(writeCo) {
            $('#writeCos').append('<option th:value="${writingCo.id}" th:text="${writingCo.companyName}"></option>')
        }
});
```

Or if I only need to do one AJAX call would it be something like this?

```js
$('#parentCo').on('change', function(event) {
  $('#parentCo').find('option:selected');
  var id = $('#parentCo').find('option:selected').attr('data');
  console.log(jQuery.type(id));
  var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
  var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/carrierAjax",
    data: {
      data: $('#parentCo').find('option:selected').attr('data')
    },
    cache: false,
    timeout: 600000,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
      console.log(header + ", " + token);
    },
    success: function(data) {
      //need to pass the value back from the spring controller here and append it below in an option tag...
      $('#writeCos').append('<option value=""></option>');
      console.log('successful');

    }
  });
});
```

In my controller:

```html
@RequestMapping(value="/carrierAjax", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody List <CarrierUmbrella>  getcarrierswriteco (@RequestParam("data") String data, DirectBind directBind, Model model) throws Exception{
        List <CarrierUmbrella> carrierUmbrellas = carrierUmbrellaRepository.findByCarrier(caRepository.findById(Long.parseLong(data)));
        model.addAttribute("carrierUmbrellas", carrierUmbrellas);
        return carrierUmbrellas;
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to use two ajax call ..you can do that in one ajax call just pass you `id` as parameter in ajax and retrieve selected value from your server .

Comment: @Swati I used one ajax call to pass a value back to my spring controller and that is working, but how am I supposed to also get the data back in to the success function of the ajax call to append options to the second drop down??

Comment: Are you getting required value in your success function ? what does `data` has in it ?

Comment: @Swati Looks like there was a different error in my code preventing the data from being passed. I am getting the data now. Just need to figure out how to sort through it and display what I want. Thank you!

Comment: can you add `data` which you are getting in ajax in your question ?